# Pros and Cons of Clojure http client libraries

Tags: java, http, clojure

I am trying to write a http file downloader in Clojure, and in [one of my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141029/to-write-a-downloader-clojure-java-io-or-javas-io-api?noredirect=1#comment26585271_18141029), someone commented that using a dedicated http client library is better than coding with Clojure's and Java's own api. I did some research and found some, but I couldn't figure out features, pros and cons of each. So if some one can explain how they are different and which one is a good match to my project, that would be much appreciated. :-D

**Libraries originally in Java, and corresponding Clojure wrappers:**

[Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) and its Clojure wrapper [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http)

[Apache HttpAsyncClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html) and couldn't find any Clojure wrapper.

[Netty](http://netty.io/) and Clojure "wrapper" is [Aleph](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph), I guess?

[Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) and its Clojure wrapper [http.async.client](https://github.com/neotyk/http.async.client)

**Last but not least, a Clojure library:**

[http-kit](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit)

Comment: I didn't suggest that Clojure API is better than Java API btw. What I said that Clojure API feels more natural! :)

Comment: @Chiron thanks to add that up! :-D

Answer (score 13):

I can only compare http-kit and clj-http.

clj-http:

- simple API
- HTTP client only
- a wrapper for Apache HttpComponents

http-kit:

- designed for async
- HTTP client and server, more powerful
- client API modeled after clj-http but it adds more abstractions so the cognitive load is higher

If you care about dependencies, http-kit may be a better choice because it is a standalone library with no other dependencies than clojure.core. Because of that it produces smaller uberjars. For a sample HTTP GET project:

```
clj-http:

1.2M    clj-http-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
6.7M    clj-http-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

http-kit:

65K     http-kit-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
3.8M    http-kit-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

On the other hand you may choose clj-http if you prefer to trust the battle tested Apache HttpComponents and potentially better support from bigger Java community.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to give a full comparison between the libraries you posted since I haven't used all of them. But I used [http-kit](http://http-kit.org/index.html) library before and it is really good.

http-kit is easy to use, modelled after the clj-http library by the way and it is really performant.  While this comparison isn't about your question directly it can still shed some light: [TechEmpower Frameworks Round 2](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/04/05/frameworks-round-2/)